# node ldapauth jpegPhoto decoding

Tags: node.js, ldap, openldap

I finally got node-ldapauth working with the base openldap install.

Now when the user object shows up in node I am trying to save the jpegPhoto to a file for use as the profile pic. But I cannot figure out the format

I have tried (among many other things):

```
fs.writeFileSync(jpgPath, ldapUser.jpegPhoto);
```

And:

```
var jpg = new Buffer(ldapUser.jpegPhoto, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync(jpgPath, jpg);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
const jpg = Buffer.from(ldapUser.jpegPhoto, 'binary')
fs.writeFileSync(jpgPath, jpg);
```